# CSS center divs in for-loop

Tags: html, css, primefaces

i want to center divs in a panel. Every div is created in a for-each-loop inside the panel. the problem is that they are displayed: block:
[image]

Or when i float:left: they appear like this:

[image]

As you can see the elements arent in the panel anymore when i float:left;
I am trying to let them appear centered and going left when the next element is coming, a combination of the both pictures. i have tried a lots of things but i cant get the right css. The final version should look like this:

[image]

Hope you guys can help me.

```
<p:panel header="DMS Folder" toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="500"
            style="margin-top:1%;padding-left:5%;padding-right:5%;margin-bottom:2%;"
            collapsed="false" styleClass="noBorder">
                <ui:repeat var="file" value="#{dms.files}">
                    <p:outputPanel
                        style="float:left;text-align:center;margin-right:30px;margin-bottom:2%;">
                        <p:graphicImage id="mimeType" value="#{file.file}"
                            title="#{file.fileEnd}" />
                        <br />
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{file.fileName}" style="font-size:10pt;" />
                    </p:outputPanel>
                </ui:repeat>
        </p:panel>
```

Comment: Please can you include the final generated markup and CSS. If I understand your problem correctly you probably don't want to be using `float: left;` at all, just `text-align: center;` on the parent.

Comment: Did you try putting `margin: 1% auto 2% auto` in `<p:panel>`?

Comment: All the CSS i use is inside the code. And i have tried this now and it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a container around your panel, it should have `text-align: center;`. or actually if you can add it to your `<p:panel>`, I'm not familiar with that and don't know what element it will render.

You should remove the `float: left;` from your divs, add `display: inline-block;` instead.

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/ba4q6qr8/)

for your code it should look like this

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <p:panel header="DMS Folder" toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="500"
                style="margin-top:1%;padding-left:5%;padding-right:5%;margin-bottom:2%;"
                collapsed="false" styleClass="noBorder">
                    <ui:repeat var="file" value="#{dms.files}">
                        <p:outputPanel
                            style="display: inline-block;text-align:center;margin-right:30px;margin-bottom:2%;">
                            <p:graphicImage id="mimeType" value="#{file.file}"
                                title="#{file.fileEnd}" />
                            <br />
                            <p:outputLabel value="#{file.fileName}" style="font-size:10pt;" />
                        </p:outputPanel>
                    </ui:repeat>
            </p:panel>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try using 'margin:auto' to set the  centered and 'display:flex' for the item positioning

http://jsbin.com/niroju/1/edit?html,css,console,output

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<style>
  .center {
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
  }
  .item {
    margin: 2px;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <div class="center" style="background-color:red;">
    <ui style="background-color:green; margin: auto;">
      <span class="item">item</span>
      <span class="item">item</span>
      <span class="item">item</span>
      <span class="item">item</span>
    </ui>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```